# Travelling to Medina from Mumbai

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, saudi-arabia, etihad

I've booked a flight from Mumbai, India, to Medina (Madinah), Saudi Arabia, via Abu Dhabi. I am holding a visit visa, not an umrah visa. My traveling agent told me that Etihad Airways from Abu Dhabi to Medina are only allowing umrah visa holders. What do I really need?

Comment: Your travel agency told you that you need an Umrah visa and you do not believe them?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: Only during the Hajj season is there such a restriction on the category of visas (it applies for both Jeddah and Medina). For Medina, there are no restrictions against the entry of non-muslims; and as its not the Hajj season you should have no problems boarding the flight and entering the country. If you want to confirm it, simply call Etihad Airways and they can confirm it for you. I am also not sure what is the difference between your traveling agent and the ticket agent?

Comment: In situations like this, you can always contact the airline's customer service directly, too.

Comment: Etihad's account on twitter is active, try to tweet them

Answer (score 1):

My travel agent with the one I've booked ticket says there's no such thing but make my trip agent says that I require an umrah visa to board the flight.

Make my trip agent says that only saudi airlines and jet airways are allowing visit visa, restriction is only for jeddah and madina.